# "The derivative of a sum is the sum of a derivative". What?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

According to this video at this [time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVId8KMsdUU#t=565):

"We're gonna do the chain rule here where the derivative of a sum is the sum of a derivative..."

Can anyone explain to me why
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{K}(O_k - t_k)^2 = (O_k - t_k)\frac{\partial}{\partial W}(O_k)
$$

Thank you!

Comment: It is a bit hard to explain this without context. But generally one would expect an expression such as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^K (O_k-t_k)\partial_W O_k$… The equality as stated does not make sense since on the left side, $k$ is sum-variable while right it's not...

Comment: Sorry, the variable $O_k$ is a function of $W_jk$ where $O_k = sigm(x_k*W_k)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video it is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\in K}(O_k - t_k)^2 = (O_k - t_k)\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}}(O_k)
$$

This is because the variables $O_l$, $l\neq k$ do not depend of $W_{jk}$.
Then, the terms $$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{l\neq k}(O_k - t_k)^2$$
are all 0, and remains

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}} \left[\frac{1}{2} (O_k - t_k)^2 \right]= 
(O_k - t_k)\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}}(O_k)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What happened to the ($O_k-t_k)^2$ for the other 'k's in K, though?

Comment: they are eaten by the derivative operator.

Comment: do you have another way of rationalising how the summation is "eaten" by the derivative operator?

Comment: this is because the variables $O_l, l\neq k$ do not depend on $W_{jk}$